# jquery hover live(delegate) does not work

Tags: jquery, delegates, hover, live

I have html code:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li class="">...</li>
    <li class="">...</li>
    <li class="">...</li>
</ul>
```

I want an hover effect on each li, so I have the code in jquery:

```
$('.items >li').live('hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        $(this).addClass('hover');  
    else
        $(this).removeClass('hover');  
});
```

strangely, this does not work as I anticipated, if I remove the >li in the selector like this:

```
 $('.items').live('hover', function( event ) {
       //the same as above in here
 }
```

this works on the whole ul. I also tried delegate like this:

```
$('.items').delegate('li','hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        $(this).addClass('hover');  
    else
        $(this).removeClass('hover');  
});
```

and this does not work either, does anybody spot anything wrong here?? thanks for help.

Comment: does your `li` already in DOM when document loaded or it append to DOM after whole document load?

Comment: @abdullah, thanks for your answer, but I used live, it does not matter, right?

Comment: Why you check the event type?

Comment: @saeed, I was using delegate, so I have to check the type.

Comment: do you get any errors in firebug?

Comment: no..both in chrome and firebox..no errors.

Comment: @bingjie2680: what version of jquery you are using?

Comment: it is version 1.6.1. any difference?

Comment: 1.6.1 still works for me http://jsfiddle.net/m2SwD/2/

Comment: @bingjie have you looked at mine? Do you have the page in a URL?

Comment: unfortunately no, I am testing it in my own laptop with xampp installed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

li element was already being applied a color css on it before being hovered which addes another css hover:#color to it. the later won't take effect because li element has two color css to it. it worked when I removed the prior one.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

});
```

or the short cut

```
$(function(){   

});
```

jsfiddle automatically wraps up the code in the `document.ready` handler

check if jquery is included

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

**edit**

try using

```
$('.items li').live(
```

**edit 2**

`live` support of `hover` was added in 1.4.4 and later if you are using an older version alternatively you can try this

```
$(".items li").live({
        mouseenter:
           function()
           {
                $(this).addClass('hover'); 
           },
        mouseleave:
           function()
           {
                $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
           }
       }
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2SwD/1/

Comment: i hope then you have included the `jquery.js`

Comment: $3nigma,, thanks for your persistent help....I am still scratching my head with that, it makes no sense that it is working..

Comment: yup apparently there is nothing wrong with your code ... hopefully you'll get around the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/m2SwD/

I tested on FF5.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.items > li').live('hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        $(this).addClass('hover');  
    else
        $(this).removeClass('hover');  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there should be space after > , you can also use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to narrow your search.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CSS hover class defined that will be visible when applied? (as in the jsFiddle supplied).